# Create Azure ative directory, database schema and populate user data

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a on-premises database, and I need to use Azure AD B2C. AD B2C needs to use data from the on-premises database.

So one way to implmenent it is to create a new Azure AD from the on-premises database.

The question is that how should I go about creating a new Azure AD and import database schema into the new Azure AD, and populate user data?

Is my thinking above correct?

**Update**

When setup, we migrate data first, then after migration, we need a sync job to sync the data maybe once every few hours (not sure the interval yet).

Comment: Hi @Pingpong: Do you want to retrieve data from the on-premises database (i.e. in real-time) or migrate data from on-premises to the Azure AD B2C directory before time?

Comment: When setup, we migrate data first, then after migration, we need a sync job to sync the data maybe once every few hours (not sure the interval yet).

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a Rest API that can CRUD data in your on-premise database. Using a custom policy, you can call into that Rest API:

1. to [validate user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-validation-custom),
2. to [obtain additional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom), and
3. [use migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration) can also use the Rest API if the on-premise DB has user data and you want to migrate it to Azure AD B2C.

Comment: you said, "You could setup a Rest API that can CRUD data in your on-premise database" Do you mean I don't need to migrate on-premise database to azure, and API can send request agaisnt the database? Can the database be SQL Database, not Azure AD?

Comment: You have both options. You didn't specify what does the on premise DB have. If it's user authentication data then migrating it is the best option (option#3) because you will be able to use full functionality of AAD B2C. If it's some other data, then you can migrate authentication data but use rest api to access other data from your on premise DB. That can be anything as long as it's accessible through the rest api.