# Username not email address using Resource Owner Password Credentials in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I wonder if it is possible to use username like `john.smith` instead of `john.smith@myfirm.com` in Resource Owner Password Credentials in Azure AD B2C.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc

For example like below:

```
https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_ROPC_Auth

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
username=john.smit&password=mypassword&grant_type=password&scope=openid myappId offline_access&client_id=myappId&response_type=token+id_token
```

All users are my firm's employees. We will import user data into azure AD before using B2C.

Any idea on how to setup?

**Update**

Ideally, we don't want to append @myfirm.com before sending it to B2C.

**Update 2**

Do the two links below only apply for external identity provider, like Facebook, not company azure AD?

What are the difference between these two links?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration

Again, Can I use Microsoft Graph API instead of Azure AD Graph API?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?toc=./toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: If the domain is always same, you could have the user enter `john.smith` and then send `john.smith@myfirm.com` to B2C?

Comment: it is only option I have. But ideally, it is supported by B2C which avoids the coding on our part.

Answer (score 1):

If you [create a local account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateLocalAccountUser) using [the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) in the Azure AD B2C directory using both **emailAddress** and **userName** sign-in name types, then users can sign in using either sign-in name value via the resource owner (or other sign-in) flow:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "userName",
      "value": "john.smith"
    },
    {
      "type": "emailAddress",
      "value": "john.smith@myfirm.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How can I create a local account like you mentioned? Any links would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Pingpong You can create the local account using the Azure AD Graph API. I've added links to the above answer.

Comment: Hi @Chris Padgett, thx for the links. Can you please see my update 2 regarding the links? thx in advance.

Comment: The questions on update 2 are aslo related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520702/create-azure-ative-directory-database-schema-and-populate-user-data